# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables error in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a fairly straightforward code and it gives me the above error message.
The data Exposed days data looks like

```
groupid  Quarter ExposedDays    AboveMaxDays    PatGroup Ageband sex Country
1         1       983            0              A        0 TO 18  F   E
1         2       167           10              B        0 TO 18  F   I
1         1       435           0               C        0 TO 18  F   S
The code is as follows-

y<-ExposedDays%>%
      select(ExposedDays,AboveMaxDays,PatGroup,Ageband,sex,Country)%>%
      gather("Variable","Value",ExposedDays,AboveMaxDays)%>%
      mutate(a=sum(ExposedDays), b=sum(AboveMaxDays))
```

I checked the columns on which I am applying the mutate function, and they are both numeric.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. You're `gather`ing `ExposedDays` and `AboveMaxDays` into columns `Variable` and `Value`. You cannot then calculate the sum of `ExposedDays` and `AboveMaxDays`. I recommend going through the `magrittr` chain step-by-step to see the intermediate products.

Comment: Quite right- It was an oversight on my end. Apologies for that